# Ошибка при установке Docker на Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

Работаю с докером впервые, при установке на **Windows 10** c [официального сайт](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows?tab=description), мне выдает ошибку связанную с моей версией OC

[image: Ошибка установки]

Собственно вот моя версия **Windows**

[image: Версия операционной системы]

Система была установлена по умолчанию на ноутбуке при его покупке, подскажите что мне предпринять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker контейнеры для Windows [поддерживаются](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows) Windows 10 версиями Pro, Enterprise или Education(1607 Anniversary update, Build 14393 or later), обязательно 64 битная. Ваша система видимо не соответствует данным требованиям.

> The current version of Docker for Windows runs on 64bit Windows 10
>   Pro, Enterprise and Education (1607 Anniversary Update, Build 14393 or
>   later).

[Введите в командной строке](https://vynesimozg.com/kak-otkryt-svedeniya-o-sisteme-v-windows-7-8-i-10/) msinfo32 для получения детальной информации о вашей системе. Там вы найдете точное название вашей системы.

Comment: Ну вот да, похоже на до, дело в том что у меня Windows 10 без приставки Pro, и я не понимаю, мне что покупать другую версию Windows?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов к сожалению, да. Приставка Pro - это не просто приставка, а другая версия винды с расширенными возможностями, если так можно выразиться.

Comment: Благодарю, ничего не поделать, прийдется ставить Pro.